# Callback function being skipped on jQueries .getJSON command

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following snippet of code:

```
$('input#teamName').live('blur', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    $.getJSON('api/event_company/'+value, function(data) {
      console.log('why does this not want to work?');
    });
  }
});
```

Basically all it's doing is requesting some data from the server when a form field changes. My problem is that nothing in the callback function every gets called even though I can see using firebug that it has successfully sent a request to the server and received a valid JSON response.

If I change the `getJSON` parameters to:

```
$.getJSON('api/event_company/'+value, alert('Blah'));
```

Then the alert pops up as expected. Any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Not sure about the first one, but the reason the `alert('Blah')` works is because you're not passing it as a callback. You're *calling* the alert() and passing its return value, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the JSON is invalid, the parsing will fail and the handler won't be called. From [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) docs:

> **Important**: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

See if your JSON [validates](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Your second example is not correct. It should instead be,

```
$.getJSON('api/event_company/'+value, function() {
    alert('Blah');
});
```

Comment: Arg. I forgot that I was outputting some extra data when I was debugging things earlier so I wasn't actually returning valid JSON. Thanks.